# Case statement where your first looking if a value exists, if not, execute rest of case statement

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Im trying to create a statement where im first looking to see if a value exists in a row, particularily for a "Bill-To/type code/type 2 code" | SKU combination, if a value doesnt exist, execute the rest of the case statement to assign a value to a given row. see the query below

```
select
distinct
trim(s.CBILNO) "Bill-To/type code/type 2 code",
case when trim(cm.CUSTYP) = 'EB' THEN ct2.CDES
when cm.CUSTYP = '' THEN cm.CNAME
else ct.DESC
end "Customer Parent Name",
cm.CBILNO "customer bill-To number",
s.PRODNO,
s.PRDLIN,
TRIM(CONCAT(CONCAT(TRIM(s.PRDLIN),'-'),s.PRODNO)) "SKU",
s.UPRICE "future contract price",
s.REVDAT "some date field",
lk.CODE "Discount Code",
lk.DESC "Discount Code Desc",
sp."GER"                                                                              "GER",
   sp."SP1"                                                                              "SP1",
   sp."IHC"                                                                              "IHC",
   sp."FRT"                                                                              "FRT",
   sp."PETP"                                                                                    "PETP",
   sp."VOL"                                                                              "VOL",
   sp."KWP"                                                                              "KWP",
   sp."MKP"                                                                              "MKP",
   pm.PMINVC "inventory code",

   ps.PPRC1 "New price",
    case when coalesce(s.UPRICE,0) <> 0 then s.UPRICE
    when lk.DESC ='SP1' then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'GER VOLUME SELL.PRICE' then sp."GER"
    when lk.desc = 'KWP/SP1(BEST)' and sp."KWP"<>0 then MIN(sp."SP1",sp."KWP")
    when lk.desc = 'KWP/SP1(BEST)' and sp."KWP"=0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'IH PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."IHC" <> 0 then sp."IHC"
    when lk.desc = 'IH PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."IHC" = 0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'FRT PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."FRT" <> 0 then sp."FRT"
    when lk.desc = 'FRT PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."FRT" = 0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'PTR PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."PETP" <> 0 then sp."PETP"
    when lk.desc = 'PTR PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."PETP" = 0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'FRT/SP1(BEST)' and  sp."FRT" <> 0 then min(sp."FRT",sp."SP1")
    when lk.desc =  'FRT/SP1(BEST)' and sp."FRT" = 0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'GER PLUS 10%' then sp."GER" * 1.1
    when lk.desc = 'SP1 LESS 5%' then sp."GER" * .95
    when lk.desc = 'GER PLUS 20%' then sp."GER" * 1.2
    when lk.desc = 'IHC VOLUME SELL.PRICE' then sp."IHC"
    when lk.desc = 'VOL PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."VOL" <>0 then sp."VOL"
    when lk.desc = 'VOL PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."VOL" =0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'MKP/VOL(BEST)-B(SP1)' and sp."MKP" <> 0 and sp."VOL" <> 0 then     MIN(sp."MKP",sp."VOL")
    when lk.desc = 'MKP/VOL(BEST)-B(SP1)' and sp."MKP" = 0 and sp."VOL" <> 0 then sp."VOL"
    when lk.desc = 'MKP/VOL(BEST)-B(SP1)' and sp."MKP" <> 0 and sp."VOL" = 0 then sp."MKP"
    when lk.desc = 'MKP/VOL(BEST)-B(SP1)' and sp."MKP" = 0 and sp."VOL" = 0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'KWP PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."KWP" <> 0 then sp."KWP"
    when lk.desc = 'KWP PRIMARY OR SP1 PRICING' and sp."KWP" = 0 then sp."SP1"
    when lk.desc = 'IHC(BEST)ALL-B(SP1)'   and sp."IHC" <> 0 then sp."IHC"
    when lk.desc = 'IHC(BEST)ALL-B(SP1)'   and sp."IHC" = 0 then sp."SP1"
    end as "Future Pricing"
from AM6FIL01.PRDMST00 pm
left JOIN qgpl.DOSA661L mo on
pm.PRDLIN = mo.UPDLIN
AND pm.PRODNO = mo.UPDNO
left join AM6FIL01.SCNDTL00 s on
trim(s.PRDLIN) = trim(PM.PRDLIN)
and trim(s.PRODNO)=trim(pm.PRODNO)
left join AM6FIL01.CUSMST00 cm
on (trim(s.CBILNO) = trim(cm.CBILNO))
or (trim(s.CBILNO) = trim(cm.CUSTYP))
or (trim(s.CBILNO) = trim(cm.CUSTY2))
LEFT JOIN
DOLIVAS.CUSTYPETB ct ON
ct.CODE = cm.CUSTYP
LEFT JOIN
AM6FIL01.CUSTP200 ct2 ON
ct2.CTYPE2 = cm.CUSTY2
left join
DOLIVAS.DISCCODETB lk on
lk.CODE = cm.DISCOD
left join
PRDPSC00 ps
on ps.PPRDLN = pm.PRDLIN and
 ps.PPRDNO = pm.PRODNO
left join standard_pricing sp
 on sp.PPRDLN = pm.PRDLIN
 and sp.PPRDNO = pm.PRODNO
 where PM.PMINVC not in ('D','I')
and s.REVDAT >= '20230622'
and sp."effective date" > current date
and sp."expiration date" > current date
```

Im expecting the case statement to execute the logic if no s.uprice exists. currently, if there is no value, only NULL is returned for that row in the case statement column.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You have no condition for when all comparisons fail.

That is why youe should add en `ELSE` like

```
ELSE 0
```

Further you have a lot of LEFT JOIN, so there will be some column that are NULL, so to start, why not show all columns and see if the NULL isn-ä#t caused by such NULL values

Comment: good point. added that in. still doesnt solve the problem though. thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: your query is quite hard to read, can you remove everything that is correct, i have amended my answer

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted the SQL to make it easier to read.

Just looking at your joins, and the last `CASE`, it appears that tables `s`, `lk`, and `sp` are involved.

BUT

`s` is a left join, and if it is not found, then `lk` will be null as well. Unfortunately, the first `WHEN` is false (falls through) if `s` is missing or if `s.uprice` = 0. If `s` is missing, that miss will propagate through to `cm` and then `lk`, so the rest of the `CASE` will fail as well and result in a NULL because you have no `ELSE`, as @nbk mentioned in their answer.

Make sure your joins are correct. Go through them one at a time, and make sure you are getting what you expect out. Then focus on the `CASE`.

The other issue you might be having is that strings are compared in a case sensitive manner unless you change the collating sequence. Descriptions typically have misspellings and case mismatches which can quickly derail the type of logic you have set up in your query. Code fields are much better to compare against than are description fields, and also perform better. It almost looks like you should be comparing against `cm.discode` instead of `lk.desc`.